# how to integrate the ckfinder with ckeditor in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, image, upload, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am integrating the ckfinder with ckeditor, i am little bit succeed but facing the following error while uploading any image.

> **The file browser is disabled for security reasons. Please contact your system administrator and check the CKFinder configuration file**

i have set the config file. but it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [link](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/423_Upload_Images_and_Integrate_with_CKeditor_in_AspNet.aspx) it has a working example. Download the  [ckeditor for .Net](http://download.cksource.com/CKEditor/CKEditor.NET/CKEditor.NET%203.6.4/ckeditor_aspnet_3.6.4.zip) from and place the ckeditor folder in the root of the project.

Answer (score 2):

By default the CKFinder is setup to not authorize sending files to the server.So all you need to do is go inside ckfinder/config.ascx, this is the main configuration file ,here temporarily change the CheckAuthentication() method to return true instead of false